# Which hypothesis test should I choose?

Tags: t-test, hypothesis-test

I have gait speed of two independent groups of different size (Control and PD). I want to apply hypothesis to test if there is a difference in the gait speed between the two groups. Which hypothesis test should I use and why?

I tried Wilcoxon rank sum test as the sample size varies and one sample distribution is not normal. Now I am wondering if unpaired T-test will be more appropriate as the data is numeric and the data distribution is not highly skewed.